# Bind inputs to array of objects in js file

Tags: validation, lightning-web-components, lightninginput

I am new to LWC. I ma made a UI, where i am taking inputs in array of objects. 
But i am not able to map those values in the JS file. I know how to do for single input, but not sure how to do for list of records. 
For single input put onchange and copy value to a property using event.target.value.

How can i do this for array of objects.

```
<template for:each={allRecords} for:item='record' for:index="index">
<tr key={record.Serial_Number__c} data-item="index">
    <th scope="row" data-label="Opportunity Name">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Remove" data-item={index} onclick={handleRemoveClick}>
            <lightning-button-icon
                icon-name="action:remove"
                variant="border-filled"
                data-item={index}
                alternative-text="Remove">
            </lightning-button-icon>
        </div>
    </th>
    <td data-label="Serial Number 1">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Serial Number" data-item={index}>
            <lightning-input class="serialNumber" type="text" variant="label-hidden" style="width:200px;" value={record.Serial_Number__c} onfocusout={serialNumberOut} data-item={index} required></lightning-input>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Serial Number 2">
        <div title="Serial Number 2" >
        <lightning-formatted-text class="serialNumber2" value={record.Serial_Number2__c}></lightning-formatted-text>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Serial Number 3">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Serial Number 3">
            <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" style="width:200px;" value={record.Serial_Number3__c}></lightning-input>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import checkSerialNumber from '@salesforce/apex/Cntrl.checkSerialNumber';
export default class PackageReportingForDealers extends LightningElement {
@track allRecords = [];
addNewRow(event){
    debugger;
    let allRecordsTemp = [];
    if(this.allRecords.length > 0) {
        allRecordsTemp = this.allRecords;
        allRecordsTemp.push(
            {Serial_Number__c : "", Serial_Number1__c : "", Serial_Number2__c : "", Serial_Number3__c : ""}
        );
    }
    else {
        allRecordsTemp.push(
            {Serial_Number__c : "", Serial_Number1__c : "", Serial_Number2__c : "", Serial_Number3__c : ""}
        );
    }
    this.allRecords = allRecordsTemp;

}

//allRecordsTemparray = [];
handleRemoveClick(event){
    debugger;
    let index = event.target.dataset.item;
    if(index) {
        alert('index::'+index);
        //this.allRecords.splice(index, 1);
        this.allRecords = this.allRecords
            .slice(0, index)
            .concat(this.allRecords.slice(index + 1));
    }
    // tried  splice also..
    this.allRecords.splicae(0, index);
    // works but sometimes deletes reocrds from wrong index.. // not sure why..  


}

handleSubmit(event) {
    debugger;
    console.log(event);
    let validated = true;
    let inputs = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
    inputs.forEach(element => {
        if(element.checkValidity() === false) {
            validated = false;
        }
    });
    if(validated) {
        //alert('Success...'); 
        // As i know, it wount bind values automatically like in Aura Comp.. 
        // So how can i bind input values to allRecords[] ??
        // i have seen for one reocord i can call onchange and use event.target.value and copy to a property.
        // but how can i do this for array of objects. ??

    }
    else {
        alert('Error...');
    }
}
```

}

My Problem is

1. How can i map inputs to allRecordsTemp[], in handleSubmit functuion. Before 
   sending to controller.
2. I am having trouble with removing array from an index, sometime it works 
   sometime doesn't. And i also again temp array to render on account. Any help on this how can i remove array from an index properly? any sample code?

Please help me with this or any link where i can get this kind of sample code. 
Thanks in advance.

Manohar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i map inputs to allRecordsTemp[], in handleSubmit functuion. Before sending to controller.

Define `onchange` on input:

```
<lightning-input class="serialNumber" type="text" data-item={index} onchange={getEnteredText}
                     required>
    </lightning-input>
```

implement `getEnteredText` in JS:

```
getEnteredText(event) {
    let ind = event.target.dataset.item;
    let enteredRecord = this.allRecords.find((rec, index) => index === parseInt(ind, 10));
    enteredRecord.Serial_Number__c = event.target.value;
    console.log("this.allRecords => ", JSON.stringify(this.allRecords));
}
```

In the log, you will see that the correct record has been updated.

> I am having trouble with removing array from an index, sometime it works sometime doesn't. And i also again temp array to render on account. Any help on this how can i remove array from an index properly? any sample code?

**It is because you do not have a proper `key` available in array. LWC iteration uses the `key` to properly render array correctly.**

You need array like below:

```
@track allRecords = [
    { id:"1", Serial_Number__c: "", Serial_Number1__c: "", Serial_Number2__c: "", Serial_Number3__c: "" },
    { id: "2", Serial_Number__c: "", Serial_Number1__c: "", Serial_Number2__c: "", Serial_Number3__c: "" },
    { id: "3", Serial_Number__c: "", Serial_Number1__c: "", Serial_Number2__c: "", Serial_Number3__c: "" },
    { id: "4", Serial_Number__c: "", Serial_Number1__c: "", Serial_Number2__c: "", Serial_Number3__c: "" }
]
```

and you need to use key as `key={record.id}`

Now you can use below `handleRemoveClick` method:

```
handleRemoveClick(event) {
    let ind = event.target.dataset.item;
    this.allRecords = this.allRecords.filter((rec, index) => index !== parseInt(ind, 10));
}
```

**NOTE:**

You will have problem in below lines also:

```
let inputs = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
inputs.forEach(element => {
    if(element.checkValidity() === false) {
        validated = false;
    }
});
```

You will get `validated` true if 3rd record is INVALID and 4th record is VALID. So, you need `break;`

```
if(element.checkValidity() === false) {
        validated = false;
    }
```

**Or else you can simply get validity by below line:**

```
let validity = !this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').find(elem => !elem.checkValidity());
```

Comment: Thanks once again @salesforce-sas for your help.
But  this line is not working for me.. 

let validity = !this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').find(elem => !elem.checkValidity());

saying find() is not a function. but my validation seems to be working.. because i not not setting VALID true, i am only setting it true.